# localhost:8080 not working but tomcat server working in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, localhost, tomcat8

I have developed a web application. The app is configured to run on tomcat server 8.5 on port 9000. When deploying the project it runs on localhost:9000. But localhost:8080 not working. I have checked the server.xml and it is configured to run on port 8080. The other tomcat 7 runs on localhost:9090.
Earlier I manually stop the server while deploying the project on IntelliJ since the project was configured to run on port 8080 and it shows error "port 8080 already in use."

Why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried closing existing running processes? That could explain 8080 already in use.

What happens when You are running tomcat from intellij, then server.xml configuration is not respected as it is overwritten by Intellij's tomcat configuration.

One is able to define his own server.xml or context.xml by specified folder under `Tomcat base directory` where those files are located. One is able to find `Tomcat base directory` when clicking `Configure` close to `Application server` entry.

Comment: When I'm closing IntelliJ and running localhost:8080 its still not working. Moreover, tomcat 8.5 is also not starting outside IntelliJ.